Lark sheet query formuala
I use query function in Larksuite sheet to filter some date value but it doesn't work. I want to get data in range A4:B7 where A = '2024-09-16' but it shows nothing. I change switch to > (Greater than) operator, it works. More details in attached photo. Could someone please help?

